# Vanilla JS Hover Event Firing on Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Like the title says, a page I'm working on is firing a hover event on page load.

### Javascript

```
// Random Color Function
var repeater;
function rnd_color(){
    document.getElementById('logo').style.fill = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    repeater = setTimeout( function(){ rnd_color(el) }, 100);
};

// Logo Hover
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
logo.addEventListener('mouseover', rnd_color, false);
logo.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    clearTimeout(repeater);
    this.style.fill = '#000';
});
```

The above is of course wrapped in a 'DOMContentLoaded' wrapper.

### HTML

```
<svg class='menu-logo' id='logo' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 170 105.5"> <!-- PATHS AND FILLS HERE --> </svg>
```

So this function is just a fun easter egg - once you hover over the svg, it fires off a new fill color every 1/10 of a second. Everything else about it works just fine except that, upon loading the page, the color function immediately begins running. Once you move the mouse at all, the appropriate 'mouseout' event takes care of refilling the svg to #000.

Even stranger, upon loading a cached version of the page, the error disappears. This only appears to happen on a completely new load of the page. Any possibility that this is a race condition of some sort even though this is wrapped in the appropriate Event Listener? Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to repro your issue but I did change your scripts around, maybe it will help. 

https://codepen.io/cidicles/pen/QxGLjB?editors=1111

Comment: Just tried the same code in my local instance - I'm getting the same error at the same consistency. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I won't say that I found a completely supported **answer** per se, but I did find the **cause** of my problem which, unfortunately, was not necessarily included in the statement of my question.

This element in question resides at 0,0 on my viewport. It's a large fixed logo that fits into a table-like layout. It would appear that, in certain instances of loading the site such as an incognito or cache-less view (the latter being somewhat inconsistent), the initial cursor position prior to the mouse moving is always set at 0,0 until the mouse has moved.

This raises some questions on the consistency of where the cursor is located upon repeat views of pages and whether or not it can be set programatically. There are a couple of ways around it for now.